# jQuery replacement for .load()?

Tags: jquery, load, deprecated

I'm stuck with my stuff here, 'cause it has been developed by one of my former colleagues.

It's all about the following line:

```
$("#selector").load(helper.GetID() + "/Shop/Payment", data, function () { .... })
```

As .load()  is deprecated, what would be the correct new line for this?
I've already tried

```
$("#selector").on("load", helper.GetID() + "/Shop/Payment", data, function () { .... })
```

but this does not seem to work for me.
Can anyone help?

Comment: `.load` is a shortcut for `.ajax`, so if you really felt you needed to remove it, then you could replace with `.ajax`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `load()` as an *event handler* is deprecated.

Using `load()` to retrieve external content - which is what you're doing - is absolutely fine. You do not need to amend your code at all.

Comment: then I'm currently on a complete wrong path here and there is something else going wrong.... thanks anyway!